# How to partially update a spark dataframe (update some rows)

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.5.2 with Python3. I have two dataframes in pyspark. They look like:

```
old_df = 

src | rank
------ | ------
  a|   1
  b|   1
  c|   1
  d|   1
  e|   1
  f|   1
  g|   1
```

and

```
new_df = 
src|              rank
---|-----------------
  a|               0.5
  b|0.3333333333333333
  c|1.6666666666666665
  d|               1.5
```

Now I want to update some rows in `old_df` with new values in `new_df`. My goal is to generate a new dataframe, which looks like:

```
  src | rank
------ | ------
  a|               0.5
  b|0.3333333333333333
  c|1.6666666666666665
  d|               1.5
  e|   1
  f|   1
  g|   1
```

The solution I came up with is to first concatenate two dataframes and then perform `dropduplicates`.

```
new_df = new_df.unionAll(old_df).dropDuplicates(['src'])
```

However, to my disappointment, Spark didn't keep the first record when performing the "drop" action, which resulted in a wrong dataframe.

Is there any approache to fix it? Or any alternative way to get the job done?

Comment: Your example works perfectly for me, what is wrong with your solution ?

Comment: The `dropduplicates` action seems to drop duplicated records at random. This behavior seems to depend on Spark version. My solution works on Spark 1.6.2 but fails on Spark 1.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this with sql functions and join..

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.funtions._

odl_df.join(new_df, "src")
  .withColumn("finalRank",
         when(new_df("rank").isNull, odl_df("rank"))
          .otherwise(new_df("rank"))
  .drop(new_df("rank"))
  .drop(odl_df("rank"))
  .withColumnRenamed("finalRank", "rank")
```

This assert that new rank is always in final df.